# How to configure resource handling by mocha-phatomJS? Error loading resource file:

Tags: unit-testing, phantomjs, mocha.js, mocha-phantomjs

I'm running test using [mocha-phantomjs](http://metaskills.net/mocha-phantomjs/).

While running an unit test, I'm not running http server, so my resources are not available through absolute urls (eg: */static/images/face.png*), and I'm getting following output:

```coffeescript
% node_modules/mocha-phantomjs/bin/mocha-phantomjs test/runner/runner.html

  test app.Main
    ✓ should show a command line 


  1 test complete (79 ms)

Error loading resource file:///static/images/face.png (203). Details: Error opening /static/images/face.png: No such file or directory
```

My test:

```coffeescript
describe "test app.Main", ->
  beforeEach ->
    @app = App.Main()
    React.renderComponent @app, root[0]

  afterEach -> React.unmountComponentAtNode root[0]

  it "should show a command line", ->
    @cmdForm = root.find("div.header-block").first().find('form')

    expect(@cmdForm.length).to.equal 1
    expect(@cmdForm.find('div.select2-container ul.select2-choices').length).equal 1
```

The test succeed, but in the mean time I have this ugly error messages.
How to configure phantomJS (or mocha?) to ignore loading that resources / not presenting this error messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to disable the [loadImages](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/settings.html) default `mocha-phantomjs -s loadImages=false`

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @reubano i.e. setting `loadImages=false` prevents phantomjs from loading images at all, and thus is what @robert-zaremba was looking for. However, if you need to unit test how your code reacts to missing files, you want the files to be really loaded. In that case the error messages will annoy you because testing for missing files is a part of your test suite.

Fortunately [mocha-phantomjs](https://github.com/nathanboktae/mocha-phantomjs) has a flag `--ignore-resource-errors`. It is your saviour. The files are still loaded but the annoying errors are gone.

If you use phantomjs directly a solution would be to override `page.onResourceError` [described here](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html).

Answer (score -1):

You could use a `window.onError(function() {...` handler to catch (and eat) those errors.

Comment: this is not an exception (tests pass) - but an error log from phantomJS.